# Max Pipe Commands of Linux

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I wrote a simple shell recently. This problem came up while I implemented the pipe.

I knew the maximum length of command line argument in Ubuntu is 2097152. (By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin))

```
#define MAX_CMD_LEN 2097152
```

But I wanted to know is there a maximum number of pipe commands? 
For example: (the number of n)

```
ps -aux |　grep "a.out" | awk '{print $5}' | top | ... | cat
1       |  2            | 3                | 4   | ... | n
```

Comment: I do not *think* there will be any limit on the maximum limit as the pipe itself does not impose any resource constraint. If you are talking about pipe buffer, then the answer is *yes*, we are constrained by the memory limit.

Comment: Sure, but that's just heap, same as anything else.

Comment: Your `MAX_CMD_LEN` limit is system specific: it is different on my Debian/Linux running 3.17 kernel...

Comment: Going off on a bit of a tangent, by the way -- if you're looking to write a script that generates very long pipelines, doing so recursively can be a source of fun and profit. See for instance my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898939/handling-long-edit-lists-in-xmlstarlet

Comment: The limits are going to bigger than you want to construct, even if you use a program to write the pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not such a limit. For a single process table entry, `ARG_MAX` applies (to combined environment and argv length). However, a pipeline spans separate process table entries, and each piece connects only to the process before it (via stdin) and the process after it (via stdout). There's no single place the entire pipeline needs to be stored or tracked as a unit inside the operating system itself (as opposed to the constructing shell).

Comment: Technically, I believe the limiting factor is the number of processes. It can be limited with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) `RLIMIT_NPROC`

Comment: Right -- but if (as is the case) the maximum number of processes you can have in a pipeline matches the maximum number of processes you could have individually with no connection between them, I'm calling it entirely fair to say that there is no limit on pipeline length.

Answer (score 1):

There are not strict limits on the length of the pipeline (that is the number of commands composing it). However, the maximum number of processes can be limited with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) `RLIMIT_NPROC` and each system has some absolute limit. Likewise, the number of file descriptors can be limited with `RLIMIT_NOFILE`

Also, your shell will call [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), and that syscall can fail (and this is practically limiting).

BTW, the maximal command line should better not be a hardwired limit (it can be changed somehow). The limitation is when [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) fails. And you could use `sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)` -see [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)- to query something related.

At last [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) could be used to query some related thresholds, e.g. using `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`, `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pipe_limit`, etc.

The bottom line is that you should not build in any wired-in limits in your shell. You should just manage resources and handle failure (of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)
 and of standard functions like [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) ...). Avoid defining arbitrary builtin limits like your `MAX_CMD_LEN`  (BTW, the exact figure is not the same on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 running a kernel 3.17 which I did compile myself).

Comment: To be sure, a `pipe()` call can fail, or a `fork()` can fail. However, such failures are because no more FDs are available, or no more process table entries, or some other resource also used for things other than pipeline construction -- not because a limit _on pipeline length as such_ has been reached.

Comment: Actually, I knew `MAX_CMD_LEN` depends on kernel version. I've used a dynamic way to replace. Thanks your answer, I think some tough parts will help me not the present but the future.

Comment: I believe even that your `MAX_CMD_LEN` depend upon the system state. In particular, it might become lower if the environment has additional variables (e.g. set with bash `export` builtin)